# How to Check a Table with column "nid" for multiple values and delete them if they are present

Tags: mysql

I want to check a Column with title `nid` in my table in Mysql called `node`

I have a list of values say **17, 21 , 45, 48**

I can get the following code to find the row with `nid` being equal to **17** using the code below

```
DELETE FROM node WHERE nid = 17
```

how should i edit it to check for all values = **17,21,45,48**.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `IN` clause:

```
DELETE FROM node WHERE nid IN (17, 21, 45, 48)
```